# How to change every word that starts with a specific letter in ahk?

Tags: autohotkey

I know that ::ani::animal with change every 'ani' into 'animal'. I want to see if there is a way to change every word that starts with a to change into animal...kinda like ::a*::animal.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of the regular expression `^` Caroot is used to find pattern at the begining of the string
For example, `^abc` matches `abc123`

Comment: could you please provide an example, it doesn't work on my computer.